# TFS API Console Application opens and closes

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to run this but the console application runs and closes.

I'm guessing the query is pulling blank or null but I made sure there is an active workitem.

I'm just trying to get it to pull back anything at this point.

```
try
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://(server):8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));

            var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

            // Sample query string.
            string wiqlQuery = "SELECT System.ID, System.Title from workitems ";

            // Execute the query.
            WorkItemCollection witCollection = workItemStore.Query(wiqlQuery);

            // Show the ID and Title of each WorkItem returned from the query.
            foreach (WorkItem workItem in witCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", workItem.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", workItem.Title);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.Read();

        }
```

Comment: Check that you have set up the project as a Console application and not a Windows application.

Comment: How do I check this?  The output says Console Application when I go to properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must've pulled an *empty* `witCollection` causing the `foreach` to be skipped (hence the console app closing immediately). If it was null, you'd get an `NullReferenceException` instead.

Have a read here, see if it helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx